# Best practices/preferences for passing hierarchical data to views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For simplicity in an example, lets say I have data classes from an object model with the following hierarchy:

- Author

  - Book

    - Chapters

Each of these data classes only contain references to instances for their children, not their parent, for their parent they only contain the Id. For example, Book has Book.Chapters, but it does not have a reference to its parent (ie: Book.Author), instead it has the Id of the parent (ie: Book.AuthorId).

Now I want to display 'breadcrumbs' for this hierarchy in my view. But to do so, I need to get information such as Author.Name, Book.Name ... So as I see it I have the following options:

1. Create custom models for each view. ie: new SingleBookViewModel { TheAuthor = DB.GetAuthor(book.AuthorId), TheBook = book }
2. Get the data in the view itself from the book. So if I have the book view for example, I would be able to use: Author author = GetAuthor(book.AuthorId)... and do this within the razor view itself.
3. Pass the data in using the Tuple class. So for viewing a chapter I populate the Model with a Tuple with the following signature:

   ```
   Tuple<Author, Book, Chapter>
   ```

**Which method would you use? Or would you use something different?**

Currently I am using the third method, with the Tuple.

The 2nd method is likely the most 'standard'. But I dislike the idea of having to create and maintain view model classes that correspond to each of the data classes (Author, Book, Chapter) behind them.

I'd like to understand what 'best practices' people have put around something such as this... and whether using Tuples makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this with ViewModels. Each of your views will be strong typed to a ViewModel that will contain all data needed for that view. You get a collection of Authors in that ViewModel, which contain a collection of books, which contains a collection of Chapters.

As an alternative you can bind your View to a collection of Authors, and upon selection of an author make an ajax get request to a controller's action that returns the books in Json format. The same would apply to the Chapters.

Comment: Unfortunately Ajax/JSON will not assist me in anyway, because the data is static (meaning it does not change after the view is 'rendered') and being 'breadcrumbs' the information needs to be shown to the user from the very start.

Comment: Then create a ViewModel object that wraps all data you need, even the data that should be displayed in the breadcrumb. Your view just renders whatever it receives. Wouldn't this work?

Comment: Yes. The only drawback is what I mentioned in my question regarding the creation/maintenance hit of these view models.

Comment: Correct, but as your View needs more and more data, maybe even unrelated in itself, you will have to find a way to feed it to the View. And the ViewModel is perfect as you can easily add another property to it. Also, if you pack all your data nice and tidy in the ViewModel, you will end up having a View that just displays whatever it gets (Breadcrumb included), and that's a good practice in itself.